# Vertical alignment issue with tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment

Look at the following image and notice that `$2$` is no vertically aligned with `$1+i$` and `$1-i$`

[image]

Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,decorations.markings,quotes}
\tikzset{close/.style={outer sep=-2pt}}
\usepackage[outline]{contour}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        dot/.style = {circle,
            draw,
            fill,
            inner sep=1.5pt}
        ]
        % curve above
        %---nodes---
        \node (Spec-Gauss) [label=center:${\text{Spec}(\mathbb{Z}[\,i\,])}$]{};
        \node (zero) [right = 1.5 cm of Spec-Gauss,
            dot,
            label=left:$0$]{};
        \node (two) [above right = 1 cm and 1 cm of zero,
            dot,
            "$1+i\vphantom{\big|}$"]{};
        %---curve---
        \draw [] (zero)
        to [out=45, in=180] (two);
        % curve below
        %--- nodes---
        \node (two-b)[below = 2 cm of two,
            dot,
            label=below:$1-i\vphantom{\big|}$]{};
        %---curve---
        \draw [] (zero)
        to [out=-45, in=180] (two-b);
        % integer line
        %---nodes---
        \node (Spec-Z) [below=2.5 cm of Spec-Gauss,
            label=center:${\text{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})}$]{};
        \node (zero-z) [right= 1.5 cm of Spec-Z,
            dot,
            "$0$"]{};
        \node (two-z) [right=1cm of zero-z,
            dot,
            "$2$"]{};
        %---line---
        \draw [] (zero-z)
            to (two-z);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Unfortunately ... when we copy your code, it can't compile ...

Comment: Can you make a sketch which shows how you want the alignment to be?

Comment: WHY does it compile at all on your system ?? Lots of errors ...

Comment: @MS-SPO - Thanks. And sorry about that. Does it compile now?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I would like the node with label `2` to be aligned with the (correctly aligned) nodes `1+i` and `1-i`.

Comment: @MS-SPO I'm deeply sorry. A bunch of packages were missing. I've tested with Overleaf and it compiles now.

Comment: Is `\node (two-z) [right=0.95cm of zero-z,dot,"$2$"]{};` what you want? If not please explain in your question how you want things to be aligned.

Comment: @LeandroCaniglia, right, I now can compile it and see everything besides the red rectangle ...

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I want to somehow get node labeled `2` to be in the vertical line going thru nodes 1+i and 1-i. However, I don't want to achieve that by means of a magical constant like 0.95 cm. I would like to use relative positions as in the other nodes which specify integer multiples of 0.50 cm such as 1, 1.5, 2 and 2.5 cm.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue is that `positioning` commands measure distance from the *edges* of the nodes, not the centers. To measure from the center of the previous node, use `right = 2cm of Spec-Gauss.center`. To measure to the center of the current node, add `anchor=center`.

Then you can place Spec(ℤ) as the node contents instead of as a label for an empty node.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, quotes}

\usetikzlibrary[fit]

\tikzset{dot/.style = {circle, draw, fill, inner sep=1.5pt}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        % curve above
        %---nodes---
        \node (Spec-Gauss) {$\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{Z}[\,i\,])$};
        \node (zero) [right = 2cm of Spec-Gauss.center, anchor=center, dot, label=left:$0$]{};
        \node (two) [above right = 1 cm and 1 cm of zero.center, anchor=center, dot, label=above:$1+i$]{};
        %---curve---
        \draw (zero) to [out=45, in=180] (two);
        % curve below
        %--- nodes---
        \node (two-b)[below = 2 cm of two.center, anchor=center, dot, label=below:$1-i$]{};
        %---curve---
        \draw (zero) to [out=-45, in=180] (two-b);
        % integer line
        %---nodes---
        \node (Spec-Z) [below=2.5 cm of Spec-Gauss.center, anchor=center]{${\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})}$};
        \node (zero-z) [below=2.5 cm of zero.center, anchor=center, dot, "$0$"]{};
        \node (two-z) [right=1cm of zero-z.center, anchor=center, dot, "$2$"]{};
        %---line---
        \draw (zero-z) to (two-z);
        \node[draw, fit=(two)(two-z), red, inner sep=0pt]{};
        \node[draw, fit=(zero)(zero-z), red, inner sep=0pt]{};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```